# Using M-Test to show you can differentiate term by term.

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I have the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{n-1}n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{d\lambda}\big(\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} \big)$

and I would like it to be $\frac{d}{d\lambda}\big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!})$.

I'm trying to show that this sequence of functions converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ and so I'm trying the M-Test.  So I need to find bounds $M_n$ for $\big|\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\big|$, such that $\sum M_n$ converges.

Thanks.  This is in order to show that I can actually do the differentiation term by term.

Comment: It doesn't converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ :( But it converges uniformly on every $[-K,K]$ :D The latter suffices.

Comment: Right...I always hear uniform convergence on compact sets about this and that.  I understand what that means...but I don't have a good feel for why it's enough.

Comment: Because differentiation is something local, it involves only the values near $x$, you don't need to care what happens at $x + 10^{10^{10^{10}}}$ or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deal with a power series with radius of convergence $R=+\infty$ so you can differentiate term by term.

Comment: You mean any power series with a radius of convergence of $\infty$ can be differentiated term by term?

Comment: @David Any power series can be differentiated term by term within its radius of convergence (because the convergence is locally uniform).